# Can not get monkey-form-data

Tags: php, html, forms, http, post

**Introduction:**

I am reading form-data through a post-request with php.
Typically you have to put a `<input type="submit">` at the end of the form to reload the page and get the data out of the form.

My code works with includes so the input-tag would reload the **"home.php"**-page. Instead of using the input-tag I tried to get the page-reloading with an a-tag which refers to `home.php?enter=guest`. Now i do not get the data out of the form. The input-tag does basically the same thing as my a-tag. Why isn't it working now?

**Code:**

*home.php:*

```
 if (isset($_GET['enter'])) {
        switch ($_GET['enter']) {
            case 'guest':
                include('./components/guest.php');    
                break;
            case 'login':
                include('./components/login.php');
                break;
            default:
                include('./components/signup.php');
                break;
        }
    }
```

guest.php:

```
<?php
if (
    isset($_POST['name']) &&
    isset($_POST['lastname'])
) {
    echo $_POST['name'];
} else {
    echo "not in";
    generateGuestLogin();
}


function generateGuestLogin()
{
    echo "
    <div class='guest-login-wrapper'>        
        <form action='./home.php?enter=guest' method='post' id='guestin'>
            <h3 id='login_headline'>(Guest) Log in</h3>
            <div id='signup-grid'>
                <div id='input-box'>
                    <input type='text' id='name' class='input' name='name' placeholder='First name' required>
                    <br>
                    <input type='text' id='lastname' class='input' name='lastname' placeholder='Last name' required>
                    <br>
                    <input type='text' id='guest-id' readonly class='input' name='guest-id' placeholder='Guest-ID' required>
                </div>
                <a href='./home.php?enter=guest' id='guest-link'>
                    <img src='./img/guest.svg' id='guest-icon' alt='guest'>
                </a>
            </div>
        </form>
            </div>
    ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An `<a>` tag is a self-contained tag that includes all information for an HTTP GET request in the `href` attribute. An `<input type="submit">` has no `href`, and instead instructs the `<form>` to perform an HTTP GET request, and build the query string from any of the inputs that are active.

Further, an `<a>` tag cannot perform an HTTP POST, although JavaScript event listeners can be used to do whatever you want.

Comment: first of all thanks nice to know. 
Yeah sure they can but i a want do that server-side. Is there anything i can work with? to hinde the input-tag behind the image(replacing it) or something?

Comment: Why can't you use the `<input>` tag, it exists for a reason. Some people will POST to the "update" page and then immediately redirect, maybe that's a pattern that would work for you?

Comment: yeah surely i could use the input tag but it would not match the icon-based design. What do you mean with update page? Has this pattern a name?

Comment: Almost all HTML tags are the same, they just have a set of default styles. Give it a class if that helps, unset a couple of things and re-style it to match the link version. Also, there's the `<button>` tag which can hold images. If the POST and redirect pattern has a name, I'm not aware of it. But the redirect is nice because then if someone hits "refresh" on their browser, they won't get the "Are you sure you want to resubmit the form data" warning.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button exist.